# my app with broadcast receiver and wifi

Tags: android

I, this is my firt app with android and i'm trying to comunicate with hardware because for me it's exciting!

when i disable wifi or i change network.... i need to make toast and vibrate. IT RUNS only on avd 2.3.3. why? i've tryied on avd 4.1.2, on samsung galaxy s2 4.1.2, on avd 4.4.2, on nexus 7 4.4.2 but nothing....

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="dado.wifibc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk 
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<receiver 
android:name="dado.wiibc.Receiver">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

receiver.java

```
package dado.wifibc;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver { 

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Toast.makeText(context, "blablabla!!!.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Vibrate the mobile phone
Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)     context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibrator.vibrate(2000);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use all these permissions in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
```